# Build result list dynamically at runtime in Slick 3.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

This works:

```
    val select = "select code,descrip from table1"
    val action = sql"#$select".as[(Int,String)]
    val future = db1.run(action.asTry)
```

But I need the number of columns in the select to be built dynamically at runtime, therefore the `as` needs to be dynamic as well:

```
    val action = sql"#$select".as[(Int,String, .... defined at runtime ....)]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Slick is a type-safe library. It will force you to use compile time types. If you have no choice but to use Slick then you can look into Shapeless and `HList`. Or you can choose to use a library which is more forgiving. Evaluate the trade-off and update the question with that. Also, please mention if you have some requirements of compile time checks.

Comment: Actually just getting it to work is easy, you can just do `val action = sql"#$select".as[Product]` and it will work. But the real problem will then be to use the result as it will be of `type Product`